# Access command line before main started

Tags: c++, linux, initialization, program-entry-point, argv

Is there a way to access `argv` from a static initializer before `main()` has been started?

```
class FooInitializer {
  public:
    FooInitializer() {
      // do something funny depending on argv
    }
};

FooInitializer initializer;


main(int argc, char** argv) {
}
```

I'll be happy with a linux specific solution.

Comment: Perhaps Linux has a function similar to Windows' `GetCommandLine`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the command line arguments passed to an application in Linux from the `proc/self/cmdline` file. This contains the full command line with each argument separated by a null byte (0 value). The last argument is always followed by an additional null byte. The example below shows how to read the arguments from `proc/self/cmdline` and output them to the console.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

void printargs()
{
    std::ifstream cmdline("/proc/self/cmdline", std::ifstream::binary);
    if(cmdline.is_open())
    {
        for(std::string arg; std::getline(cmdline, arg); )
        {
            std::cout << "arg:" << arg << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printargs();
}
```